# Accessing Forwarded Host from a redirected request

Tags: python, http, wsgi, web.py

I'm working on an application which will be serving as a Centralized Authentication System for  multiple other applications. Each application will have an `APPLICATION_KEY` associated with it's domain name.

Applications will send this `APPLICATION_KEY` to the Centralized Application for authentication. Centralized Application then verifies the `APPLICATION_KEY` and the Forwarded Host/Referrer; if validated forwards the request for the further processing.

So far so good, the issue comes in when I create an application and simply redirect it with the `APPLICATION_KEY` to the Centralized Application. In case of HTTP redirects (302 or 301), the forwarded host does not appear in the request object and so the application authentication fails.

Is there a better and reliable way for implementing the same process instead of using Forwarded Host or Referrer from request object? Any suggestions or pointers will be really helpful.

Comment: Beats me, but this is something that I'd like to know too, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on a header that is easily faked is not a good way to enforce security.

Normally, when you have a central authentication service, the user is redirected to the CAS with a token identifying the application.

The user enters their credentials.

If authentication succeeds, then the CAS service checks the user's authorization for that application; and then redirects the user back to the application with an authentication token that contains their authorization.

The destination for the redirect is passed in as part of the request to the CAS service:

```
http://mycas.service/auth?token=ABC123FDSR&back=/foo/bar.html
```

In some implementations, the redirect URL is sent in the body of a POST request. This kind of implementation is usually done on controlled systems (ie, not usually on the Internet).

To prevent forging of the tokens; any combination of the following are applied:

1. Login is restricted from certain IPs (again, on a controlled network this is possible).
2. The token is generated using a shared key using a PKI.
3. An arbiter service is used to authenticate both the CAS and the application.

For public facing systems - the implementation is done the other way around; that is, the user authenticates the app:

1. User logs in to the CAS service.
2. User generates tokens for apps registered on the service.
3. User logins to the target application.
4. Target application redirects user to CAS service.
5. User logs into the CAS service.
6. Credential token generated in step 2 is passed back to the application.

Of course there are other ways to implement the same, but instead of cooking this yourself use something like [shibboleth](https://shibboleth.net/) or [crowd](https://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/overview).

Comment: I have implemented it exactly as you have mentioned it. However, in case somehow the token is compromised and some other application fakes the request, I do not have a way to discard it.